# How to use mysql_errno() inside own error handling function?

Tags: php, mysql

I want to use my own error handling and my first thought was this:

```
// db connection
$conn = conn();
if(!$conn)
$aErrors[] = 'Fout: Geen database verbinding!';


function db_error($conn)
{
if(mysql_errno($conn) == 0)
    return true;
else
{
    // log! and global $aErrors[] =  mysql_errno($conn)
    return false;
}
}

$q = "SELECT 
   xusername, email
FROM 
   terra_user
WHERE
   ID = '".$_GET['ID']."'
LIMIT 1";

$exec = mysql_query($q);

// error check
if(db_error($exec))
{
echo'teeeeeest!';
}
else
{
   $aRow = mysql_fetch_assoc($exec);

   $uitgever = $aRow['username'];
   $uitgever_email = $aRow['email'];
   echo'Xteeeeeest!';
}
```

But I get the next error:

> Warning: mysql_errno(): supplied argument is not a valid MySQL-Link resource in xxxx

In this case, `mysql_erro()` returns a number > 0, so it looks OK, except that the link source is not OK?

If I use `mysql_errno($conn)` I get :

> Warning: mysql_fetch_assoc(): supplied argument is not a valid MySQL result resource in xxxxxx

In this case, `mysql_erro()` returns 0!

For this code I have changed one field with a wrong name. Put an extra x for username:)
`$_GET['ID']` is already tested with `ctype_digit($_GET['ID'])`

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: what's the point in this function at all?

Comment: i am lazy, so after executing a query, i only have to check if dberror() returns true and if false, it will handle logging my errors, sending mail/sms. But this is just a start of it. When this part works, i will extend it.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Warning: mysql_fetch_* expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given error](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11674312/warning-mysql-fetch-expects-parameter-1-to-be-resource-boolean-given-error)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see no point in such a function at all. You have $exec for your error "handling", that's enough.

```
// db connection
$conn = conn();
if(!$conn) {
    $aErrors[] = 'Fout: Geen database verbinding!';
}

$q = "SELECT xusername, email FROM terra_user WHERE ID = ".(int)$_GET['ID']." LIMIT 1";
$exec = mysql_query($q) or trigger_error(mysql_error());

// error check
if(!$exec))
{
    $aErrors[] = 'Fout: Geen database verbinding!';
}
else
{
   $aRow = mysql_fetch_assoc($exec);
   $uitgever = $aRow['username'];
   $uitgever_email = $aRow['email'];
   echo'Xteeeeeest!';
}
```

Though I see no point in collecting errors into array. if it's critical error, no need to wait for the other - only one is enough. if it's not a critical error - why disturb a user with it?

Comment: Thank you! I was wasting my brains and time on the wrong issue!

Comment: This is just the beginning. $aErrors is just a debugging tool for me. $aMessages is an array ment for visitors.

Comment: hi, usually i make a difference between "user" errors and php errors. like ini_set ('display_errors', 0);
ini_set ('log_errors', 3);
ini_set ('error_log', '/home/xxxxxx.nl/public_html/Maintenance/phperrorlog.txt');
error_reporting(E_ALL); in my script i just abused $aErrors to get it displayed. Normally this array is used for tracking user abuse of the site and therefore i have a seperated table to store certain actions or if a user do something  unexected, as far as i can notice it, like multiple accounts, unexpected user values etc.